# Override a specific argument in all django model queries?

Tags: django

I have a custom django user model that does not contain a username field, it uses email instead. I am attempting to implement a 3rd party package that makes queries to the user model based on `username`. Is there a way to override all queries (get, filter, etc.) to this model through a custom manager or otherwise so that `username` is simply converted to `email`?

It would turn this:

```
User.objects.filter(username="grrrrrr@grrrrrr.com")
```

into

```
User.objects.filter(email="grrrrrr@grrrrrr.com")
```

Comment: The utility method BaseUserManager.get_by_natural_key will lookup the user using the field specified by USERNAME_FIELD in your custom User model  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager.get_by_natural_key. `User.objects.get_by_natural_key("grrrrrr@grrrrrr.com")`

Comment: @IainShelvington the actual query is made by the 3rd party package,  so I am unable to change the query itself

Comment: Overriding the `filter` method is doable but there are so many ways a field can be used in a query that it would be extremely complex to cover them all. Which package is it that you are having issues with?

Comment: The package is https://github.com/fangli/django-saml2-auth, it looks like we could get away with just overriding get and filter. My thinking was that if `get_queryset` could somehow be overwritten to just swap username for email that would be nice and clean. Not seeing a solution yet, possibly `QuerySet.query`? This is a little out of my league...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a QuerySet subclass where you "clean" the incoming kwargs for the `get` and `filter` methods and change username to email

```
class UserQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def _clean_kwargs(self, kwargs):
        if 'username' in kwargs:
            kwargs['email'] = kwargs['username']
            del kwargs['username']
        return kwargs

    def filter(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = self._clean_kwargs(kwargs)
        return super().filter(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = self._clean_kwargs(kwargs)
        return super().get(*args, **kwargs)


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return UserQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    
    objects = UserManager()
```

The custom manager will need to implement `create_user` and `create_superuser` as detailed [here in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-a-manager-for-a-custom-user-model)